# Get the number of rows depending on a cell value in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I am trying to get the number of rows from a `DataGridView` depending on a value from it. In the `MessageBox` should display all the number of rows that this value has on the `DataGridView`.

This is the code I got:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{   
    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Urgent")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have things to do!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

What should I do to get the number of rows depending on the `"4 - Urgent"` value?

Comment: Am confused here, do you want the _total no of rows_ OR the _specific row number_ which has "4 - Urgent" in the second index of row's item array

Comment: I want to get the number of rows that has the value "4 - Urgent" in a cell" @Nobody

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var count = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                     .Count( r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Urgent" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
 int count = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r=> r.Cell[1].Value.Tostring.Trim()== "4 - urgent").Count();
```

Comment: Does not work. It says that DataGridViewCellCollection does not contain a definition for 'Where'.

Comment: Do `Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where...`, or you don't have LINQ. You have to have `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of file

Comment: `'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: Sorry, made a silly mistake (I was looking in the cells in the row, not in the Rows collection). Edited my answer...

Comment: Kepp saying the same message that `DataGridViewCellCollection does not contain a definition for 'Where'`

Comment: Still needed one addition (edited again). Sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: @JohanDonne Make last edit, add predicate in `Count` instead `Where` and you will see my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of rows , that matching your input at the first column

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> rows = dataGridView1.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals("4 - Urgent"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (dg.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Urgent") 
   //Trim() for removing whitespaces
    {
         totalCount += 1;
         MessageBox.Show(i); // this will give you the row index
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(totalCount.ToString()); //Total no of rows containing  "4 - Urgent"
```